# Is there a way of solving database errors?

Tags: python, database, flask

[Here is the image of what am getting!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XUuH.png)I have a web app where I am supposed to feed in the customer details. So I have created the database for my table, its working but the problem is that when I fill the data into the Customer form, am getting the message "Customer has been added successfully" but the customer details are not populating on the table. But when i check on the database the details are available. What might be the problem? Here is m

```
 @app.route('/delivery_app/define-customer', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def define_customer_details():
    form = DefineCustomerDetailsForm()
    if request.method == "GET":
      try:
         areas_drop_down_list = areasTbDropDownSchema.dump(AreasTb.query.all())
        form.area.choices = [(i['ID'], i['Name']) for i in areas_drop_down_list]

     except Exception as ex:
        flash(ex, "danger")

elif request.method == "POST":
    try:

        customer = CustomerTb(
            form.firstname.data,
            form.lastname.data,
            form.contactperson.data,
            form.customerType.data,
            form.email.data,
            form.phonenumber1.data,
            form.phonenumber2.data,
            form.phonenumber3.data,
            form.area.data,
            form.location.data)

        db.session.add(customer)
        db.session.commit()

    except Exception as ex:
        flash(ex, 'danger')

    flash('Customer: "' + form.firstname.data + '  ' + form.lastname.data + '" successfully added', 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('view_customers_details'))

return render_template('./delivery_app/define-customers.html', form=form)

class DefineCustomerDetailsForm(FlaskForm):
firstname = StringField('Firstname', validators=[DataRequired()])
lastname = StringField('Lastname', validators=[DataRequired()])
contactperson = StringField('Contact Person', validators=[Optional()])
# fetch the list below from db
customerType = SelectField('Customer Type', validators=[DataRequired()], 
choices=CUSTOMER_TYPE)
email = StringField('Email', validators=[Optional(), Email(message='Not a 
valid email address')])
phonenumber1 = StringField('Phone 1', validators=[DataRequired()])
phonenumber2 = StringField('Phone 2', )
phonenumber3 = StringField('Phone 3', )
area = SelectField('Area', validators=[DataRequired()])
location = StringField('Location', validators=[DataRequired()])
submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

Comment: class DefineCustomerDetailsForm(FlaskForm):
    firstname = StringField('Firstname', validators=[DataRequired()])
    lastname = StringField('Lastname', validators=[DataRequired()])
    contactperson = StringField('Contact Person', validators=[Optional()])
    # fetch the list below from db
    customerType = SelectField('Customer Type', validators=[DataRequired()], choices=CUSTOMER_TYPE)
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[Optional(), Email(message='Not a valid email address')])

Comment: phonenumber1 = StringField('Phone 1', validators=[DataRequired()])
    phonenumber2 = StringField('Phone 2', )
    phonenumber3 = StringField('Phone 3', )
    area = SelectField('Area', validators=[DataRequired()])
    location = StringField('Location', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

Comment: Please post all relevant code in your original post and not in comments.

Comment: Okay, I have added to the post

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhSeA.png)I dont understand why you have to use: elif?
The same code have run well

```
@serv.route('/add_service', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def add_service():
    email = current_user.email
    shop = Shop.query.filter_by(shop_email=email).first()
    if not shop:
        flash("Bạn chưa có quyền đăng nhập vào dashboard")
        return redirect(url_for('main.quanly'))
    else:
        rows = db.session.query(Services).count()
        new_row = rows + 1
        print("lay duoc thong tin Row ", new_row)
        form = SV_Form()
        return render_template('add_service.html', form=form, shop_name=shop.shop_name, shop_id=shop.shop_id)


@serv.route('/add_service', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def add_service_post():
    shop_id = request.args.get('shop_id')
    form = SV_Form(request.form)
    if form.is_submitted():
        print("Form successfully submitted")
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash('Success!')
        rows = db.session.query(Services).count()
        new_row = rows + 1
        print('Lay dc new_row', new_row)
        # Here I can assume that I have data and do things with it.
        # I can access each of the form elements as a data attribute on the
        # Form object.
        flash(form.service_name.data, form.service_price.data)
        new_service = Services(service_id=new_row,
                               service_name=form.service_name.data,
                               service_price=form.service_price.data,
                               service_duration=form.service_duration.data,
                               service_car_type=form.service_car_type.data,
                               service_img=form.service_img.data,
                               service_short_des=form.service_short_des.data,
                               service_long_des=form.service_long_des.data,
                               service_haravan_id=form.service_haravan_id.data,
                               service_video=form.service_video.data,
                               service_tags=form.service_tags.data,
                               shop_id=shop_id, service_car_class=form.service_car_class.data,
                               service_promotion=form.service_promotion.data)

        print(new_service)
        db.session.add(new_service)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(request.referrer)
    else:
        print(form.errors)
        return render_template('add_service.html', form=form)
```

If you user methods=['GET', 'POST'], i think you should do

```
@main.route('/datlich', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def datlich():
    Job A
    Job B
    Job C
    this area to do the GET method
    ......
    if request.method == 'POST':
       do Job to update or creat db
       return redirect(....)
    return render template(   )
```

Please be carefull to check the Form, if some field wrong, it can not run

```
class SV_Form(FlaskForm):
    """Services post form."""
    service_name = StringField('Tên dịch vụ', [DataRequired()])
    service_price = StringField('Giá dịch vụ, ví dụ: 100.000', [DataRequired()])
    service_duration = StringField('Thời gian thi công, nhập số phút', [DataRequired()])
    service_car_type = StringField('Loại xe: Mini, Sedan, HB, SUV-5, Larger', [DataRequired()])
    service_img = StringField('Link hình', [DataRequired()])
    service_short_des = TextAreaField('Mô tả ngắn', [DataRequired()], widget=TextArea())
    service_long_des = TextAreaField(
        'Các bước chi tiết, mỗi dòng cú pháp: Rửa sơ####Ủ bọt####Car star, Lotus foam - Nước rửa xe có kiềm',
        [DataRequired()], widget=TextArea())
    service_haravan_id = StringField('Service haravan id')
    service_video = StringField('Link youtube')
    service_tags = StringField('Tags')
    service_car_class = SelectField('Phân khúc', choices=[('static/img/xephothong.png', 'Xe phổ thông'),
                                                          ('static/img/xesang.png', 'Xe sang'),
                                                          ('static/img/car.png', 'Tất cả')
                                                          ])
    service_promotion = StringField('Chương trình khuyết mãi')
    service_cate = SelectField('Danh mục', choices=[
        ('Rửa xe', 'Rửa xe'),
        ('Dọn nội thất', 'Dọn nội thất'),
        ('Đánh bóng sơn', 'Đánh bóng sơn'),
        ('Rửa khoang máy', 'Rửa khoang máy'),
        ('Tẩy ố kính', 'Tẩy ố kính'),
        ('Tẩy nhựa cây', 'Tẩy nhựa cây'),
        ('Tẩy nhựa đường', 'Tẩy nhựa đường'),
        ('Phủ nano bóng sơn', 'Phủ nano bóng sơn'),
        ('Phủ ceramic sơn xe', 'Phủ ceramic sơn xe'),
        ('Dán phim cách nhiệt', 'Dán phim cách nhiệt'),
        ('Bọc ghế da', 'Bọc ghế da'),
        ('Sơn phục hồi ghế da', 'Sơn phục hồi ghế da'),
        ('Sơn phục hồi nhựa', 'Sơn phục hồi nhựa'),
        ('Sơn phủ gầm', 'Sơn phủ gầm'),
        ('Thay dầu động cơ', 'Thay dầu động cơ'),

    ])
    submit = SubmitField('Thêm & Tạo mới')
```

HTML

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="hrv-loyalty-form-body">
        <div class="row bg-dark">{% include 'nav_dashboard.html' %}</div>
<div class="ui-product-head">Welcome, {{ name }}!</div>
            <div class="ui-product-head">
                <h4>QUẢN TRỊ TRUNG TÂM CHĂM SÓC XE: {{ shop_name }}</h4>
            </div>
                    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
                    {% if messages %}
                        <div class="notification is-danger">
                            {{ messages[0] }}
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endwith %}
        <form method="POST" action="/add_service?shop_id={{ shop_id }}">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="next-label">
                        {{ form.service_name.label }}{{ form.service_name(class_="next-input") }}
                        {% for error in form.service_name.errors %}
                            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         <div class="row">

                <div class="col">
                    <div class="next-label">
                        {{ form.service_cate.label }}{{ form.service_cate(class_="next-input") }}
                        {% for error in form.service_cate.errors %}
                            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="next-label">
                        {{ form.service_price.label }} {{ form.service_price(class_="next-input") }}
                         {% for error in form.service_price.errors %}
                            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col">
                    <div class="next-label">
                        {{ form.service_duration.label }}{{ form.service_duration(class_="next-input") }}
                        {% for error in form.service_duration.errors %}
                            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="next-label">
                        {{ form.service_haravan_id.label }}{{ form.service_haravan_id(class_="next-input") }}
                        {% for error in form.service_haravan_id.errors %}
                            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="next-label">
                        {{ form.service_car_class.label }} {{ form.service_car_class(class_="next-input") }}
                         {% for error in form.service_car_class.errors %}
                            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col">
                    <div class="next-label">
                        {{ form.service_promotion.label }}{{ form.service_promotion(class_="next-input") }}
                        {% for error in form.service_promotion.errors %}
                            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="next-label">
                        {{ form.service_short_des.label }} <br>{{ form.service_short_des(class_="",rows="6", cols="185") }}
                        {% for error in form.service_short_des.errors %}
                            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="next-label ">
                        {{ form.service_long_des.label }} {{ form.service_long_des(class_="",rows = "15", cols = "185") }}
                        {% for error in form.service_long_des.errors %}
                            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="next-label">
                        {{ form.service_car_type.label }} {{ form.service_car_type(class_="next-input") }}
                        {% for error in form.service_car_type.errors %}
                            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="next-label">
                        {{ form.service_img.label }} {{ form.service_img(class_="next-input") }}
                        {% for error in form.service_img.errors %}
                            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="next-label">
                        {{ form.service_video.label }} {{ form.service_video(class_="next-input") }}
                        {% for error in form.service_video.errors %}
                            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="next-label">
                        {{ form.service_tags.label }} {{ form.service_tags(class_="next-input") }}
                        {% for error in form.service_tags.errors %}
                            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    {{ form.submit(class_="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block") }}
                    {% for error in form.submit.errors %}
                            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                </div>
             <div class="col">
                        <a href="{{ url_for('serv.list_service') }}"
                                   class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block bg-danger">
                                    Không lưu & Thoát
                                </a>

             </div>

            </div>
        </form>

    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: My flask webapp is running but the problem is that, the data is not populating on the table after being redirected ( return redirect(url_for('view_customers_details')))

Comment: I have same before when i make wrong form, or Model

Comment: Try to add this code: if form.is_submitted():
        print("Form successfully submitted")
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash('Success!')

Comment: I have added that part, but am not seeing any changes.

Comment: try print data after form.location.data) : print(form.firstname.data,
            form.lastname.data,
            form.contactperson.data,
            form.customerType.data,
            form.email.data,
            form.phonenumber1.data,
            form.phonenumber2.data,
            form.phonenumber3.data,
            form.area.data,
            form.location.datar)
        db.session.add(customer)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Customer: "' + form.firstname.data + '  ' + form.lastname.data + '" successfully added', 'success')

Comment: This is the error that I have received after adding  the print    __init__() missing 9 required positional arguments: 'last_name', 'contact_person', 'type', 'email', 'phone_number', 'phone_number2', 'phone_number3', 'area_id', and 'location'

Comment: Can the problem be arising from the HTML part?

Comment: Okay let me try make those changes

Comment: Someone has advised me to write a javascript file for the above because the javascript is imported in my HTML file, though am not good in javasript.